# How to highlight only one button out of 4 buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 4 buttons on the screen. When i click one button i am loading Grid data on the same UI.

When I click 2nd button I am just clearing old data and binding new data for the corresponding grid.

I just want to highlight only one Button once i Clicked it.

I am using MVVM pattern so.. need to fix this issue only in XAML.

Example:

I clicked 1st button it will load data on the grid based on selection.
Now button 1 should be highlighted.

When I click on 2nd button. Button 1 should be in normal state and 2nd button should be highlighted.

Only one Button highlight should be in highlighted mode until we are on the view.

Comment: It sounds like you just described a `RadioButton` Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `RadioButton`s.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RbTemplateKey" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="141,148,161,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="AliceBlue">

        <RadioButton Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource RbTemplateKey}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource RbTemplateKey}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource RbTemplateKey}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource RbTemplateKey}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohit and AnjumSKhan.. Finally I changed my Button control to RadioButton. Problem is solved.

Comment: @user2366302 someone has downvoted my answer without giving reason

Comment: I am not sure who did that.. sorry dude

Answer (score 0):

You should use WPF triggers. In your case it's **IsPressed**. Simple example:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="1"/>
    </Trigger>
```

Here is a complete example that works for me

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key = "TriggerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property = "IsPressed" Value = "True">
                <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Button x:Name="button" Style = "{StaticResource TriggerStyle}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Style = "{StaticResource TriggerStyle}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
```

If it still doesn't work then maybe you should post your xaml.

Comment: I tried with this.. When we click on 2nd button, 1st button should be in normal mode. This is not happening with this fix.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I tried with your updated answer. Only one button is showing as Red wen we click on button. But once we click on 1st button, I just clicked on tab key. Red highlight is gone for the button 1. I meant to say even if you loose the focus the Red color should be persist until we click on 2nd button.

Comment: It should work only when we click on the button. Instead of IsFocused.

Comment: My mistake changed it to `IsPressed`

Comment: If we use IsPressed, Red color is showing when we click on the button, and then red highlight is gone. It should be persist until we click on 2nd button.

Comment: please post your xaml